# Ionic Native contacts spent a lot of time and blocks UI

Tags: reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am developing with Ionic + Capacitor + React and I need to read all contacts numbers.
Using ionic-native/contacts in this way:

```
import { Contacts, ContactFindOptions } from '@ionic-native/contacts';

...

loadContacts() => {
    this.setState(
        {
            loading: true,
        },
    () => {
        var contacts = new Contacts();
        const desiderFields = ['phoneNumbers'];
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter = '';

        options.multiple = true;
        options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
        contacts.find(desiderFields, options).then((result) => { ... } );
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.loadContacts();
}
```

But as soon as loadContacts start reading contacts the UI blocks and not even the state has time to render to show the loader.

Plus, the it is very slow importing contacts, showing repeatedly `Fetching in bulk 250 contacts!`.

I know that cordova-plugin-contacts is deprecated but I can't believe that those not exists valide alternatives to this fundamental feature.

Can't find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this cordova plug-in that saved my life:

https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers

Answer (score 0):

The issue with blocking the main thread, probably has to do with that the library fetches key/value pairs like phone and email for each contact separately instead of simultaneously.

The Capacitor Community has its own contacts plugin now: https://github.com/capacitor-community/contacts

It also solves the performance issue. In fact, it was one of the first PRs to be merged: https://github.com/capacitor-community/contacts/issues/3

In a rewrite of the plugin (v3 and up), it has been incorporated into the codebase from the start. Moreover, some extra efforts were done to make it as fast as possible.

It's preferred to use the Capacitor plugin (currently maintained by me) instead of the Cordova one. Its codebase is cleaner, more up-to-date and better maintained. Moreover, it's specifically targeting Capacitor. Therefore the compatibility will be guaranteed.